# Product stock quantity

Tags: magento2, product, qty

I can't get the correct quantity from my products and i'm not able to see what I'm doing wrong.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository;

/**
 * @var ProductRepository
 */
private $productRepository;

/**
 * @var StockItemRepository
 */
private $stockItemRepository;

$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$productStock = $this->stockItemRepository->get($productId);

var_dump($productId);                  // -----> string 51
var_dump($productStock->getQty());     // -----> float 30
```

Problem is now if I check the quantity from the database.

I' going to `cataloginventory_stock_item` the qty should be 0

[image: Qty picture]

The quantity is also apearing correctly as 0 in the backend...so as I have no idea where this 30 values is coming from.

[image: qty-2]
[image: qty-3]

Comment: try to run `var_dump($productStock->getData())` then you'll get all data n check that if qty exists or not

Comment: else try this
`$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($productId);
print_r($productStockObj->getData());`

Comment: @AsadKhan Good catch printing getData revealed me that even having "51" as product id; then stock product id related is "49" which really has 30 as a quantity...this makes no  sense...but I have something to work with now with that clue.